# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Attempted to record expectation on unmockable method in jmockit

Tags: java, jmockit

```
@Test
public void verifyAttribute_getEnforceUserGroup_True()
{
    boolean flag= false;

    new MockUp<DataCache>()
    {
        @Mock
        public HashMap getSitesCache()
        {
            return map;
        }

    };

    new Expectations()
    {
        {
            cach.getSitesCache().get(anyInt);
            returns(site);

            site.getEnforceUserGroups();
            returns(1);
        }
    };

    try
    {
        flag =enforceObj.verifyAttribute();
        assertEquals(true, flag);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am unable to mock this `get(int key)` method of `HashMap` class. Cach and site are the mocked objects of their respective classes.
If I comment the `cach.getSitesCache.get(anyInt)` and add `map.get(key)` it gives the same error. My question is:

how to mock the `get(int)` method of `HashMap` class?

Here `getSitesCache()` method returns the `HashMap`. Now by passing the key as an argument of get method I got an object. Now that object is converted into Site object.

How to mock it?

Answer (score 0):

Mocking `HashMap` is not allowed; instead, the test should return a real map from `getSitesCache()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  Why is it not allowed?

Comment: Because mocking a `HashMap` is always a bad idea. Meaning, you can write a much better test *without* doing such a thing. This is a XY question, which doesn't show the actual problem that needed to be solved. It should instead focus on what is to be tested, without assuming a particular solution.

Comment: Ok, so JMockit itself does not prevent mocking of java.util.HashMap, you're just stating in general it is not a good idea.  For reference, I have since figured out how to mock a HashMap with JMockit, so one can indeed mock built-in Java classes if necessary.

Comment: In recent versions of the library, an attempt to mock `HashMap` (and several others) with `@Mocked` throws an exception (as it's disallowed). It's still allowed with a `MockUp`, though, but doing so can easily cause strange failures during test execution, since these classes are heavily used inside the JDK itself.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  I should clarify, I was able to create a mock Map (interface) using @Mocked, with JMockit v1.24.  I probably would have gotten an exception if I tried to mock the concrete HashMap class.